# How to Prove Isomorphism Between Two Quotient Fields?

Tags: polynomials, ring-isomorphism

I have following two field and would like to prove those two are isomorphism as a field.

> $F_1 = \Bbb Z_3[x] /( x^3+x^2+2)$
>
> $F_2 = \Bbb Z_3[x]/(x^3 + 2x+2)$

Then I might have to prove 1) addition and multiplication are preserved well through a specific function between $F_1$ and $F_2$ also with it well transfer identity's of one field.

However, to prove that well-preservation of operation, how could I normally think the representative element of quotient field of polynomial?

Any idea how to get those?

Comment: Let $f(x)=x^3+x^2+2$ and $g(x)=x^3+2x+2$. If $\alpha$ is a zero of $f(x)$, then $F_1=\Bbb{Z}_3(\alpha)$. Similarly if $\beta$ is a zero of $g(x)$, then $F_2=\Bbb{Z}_3(\beta)$.  Show that $x^3f(1/x)=-g(x)$. This implies that $1/\alpha$ is a zero of $g(x)$ in $F_1$. Do you see why that solves your problem?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen actually not. why does the fact that inverse of $\alpha$ being a zero in $F_1$ is equivalent to the field isomorphic relation?

Comment: Ok. We can use $\alpha=x+(f(x))\in F_1$. And $\beta=x+(g(x))\in F_2$. When constructing an isomorphism of fields $\phi:F_2\to F_1$ more or less the only thing we need to worry about is what $\phi(\beta)$ will be? You see, because $g(\beta)=0$ we must have $g(\phi(\beta))=0$ as well. Because $g(x)$ is irreducible this is also sufficient. So, what it is the inverse of $\alpha$ in $F_1$?

Comment: The above is standard stuff about algebraic field extensions. Have you covered that in general?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If we set $\phi(x) = 1/x$, don't we need to show not just for zero, but it also preserves the addition and multiplicative property of ring? Still can't get it why we only cares about 0 and it's sufficient.